# Chemical equation with "●" symbol

Tags: equations, chemistry

How to write this equation (the ● is like the +). I'm using `{chemist}` package for ordinary equations.

```
 ROO● + AH → ROOH + A●
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/draw-lewis-structures-like-a-book/137248#137248, if your question concerns Lewis structures.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With ● you probably mean the Lewis representation of an electron?

You mention the `chemist` package which is part of XyMTeX. XyMTeX has the commands `\chemradicalA[]{}` and `\chemradicalB[]{}` for denoting lewis electrons. They are described in XyMTeX's [new manual (published only a few weeks ago to CTAN, 790 pages long!)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xymtex/doc) section *23. Lone Pairs and Radicals*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemist,xymtex}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \ChemForm{%
    RO\chemradicalA[2]{O} \, + \, AH
    \reactrarrow{0pt}{1cm}{}{}
    ROOH \, + \, \chemradicalA[2]{A}
  }\\
  \ChemForm{%
    RO\chemradicalB[1]{O} \, + \, AH
    \reactrarrow{0pt}{1cm}{}{}
    ROOH \, + \, \chemradicalB[1]{A}
  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here are a few alternative possibilities using other packages than XyMTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}[2013/11/04]
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand*\pkg[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}

\pkg{mhchem}:\par
\ce{ROO. + AH -> ROOH + A.} (actually wrong)\par
\ce{ROO^. + AH -> ROOH + A^.}

\pkg{mhchem} and \pkg{chemfig}:\par
\ce{\Lewis{0.,ROO} + AH -> ROOH + \Lewis{0.,A}}

\pkg{chemformula}:\par
\ch{ROO. + AH -> ROOH + A.} (actually wrong)\par
\ch{ROO^. + AH -> ROOH + A^.}\par
\ch{"\chlewis{0.}{ROO}" + AH -> ROOH + "\chlewis{0.}{A}"} (needs an up to date
version)

\pkg{chemformula} and \pkg{chemfig}:\par
\ch{"\Lewis{0.,ROO}" + AH -> ROOH + "\Lewis{0.,A}"}

\pkg{chemfig}\par
\schemestart
  \Lewis{0.,ROO} \+ AH
  \arrow
  ROOH \+ \Lewis{0.,A}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

The versions without [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) (except the one with `\chlewis`) are not completely correct as they actually are typesetting the adduct dot and not an electron (the wrong spacing in the `chemformula`-only version tells it...)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I managed to do it using the symbol itself 
`\begin{chemmath} ROO^{\textbf{•}} + AH \longrightarrow ROOH + A^{\textbf{•}} \end{chemmath}` however I'm going to accept your answer cause it's a valid solution

Comment: @HediNaily BTW: I added a XyMTeX solution (since you've mentioned `chemist`)...