# Lewis structures in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I want to do something like this using `chemfig`. I watched the `chemfig` guide but I can't find a solution.

Can you help me?

(Sorry, my english is not very good)

[image]

Comment: If you search this site for "Lewis Structures", http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lewis%20structures, you will find several questions and answers on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

My comment provided the measn to find a number of links on the subject of Lewis Structures in LaTeX.

But here, without `chemfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifthen}
\newcommand\lewis[7]{\,%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}%
    {\def\RHS{}\def\RRHS{\hspace{.5ex}}}%
    {\def\RHS{\,\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[1.5ex]{#3}}\,}\def\RRHS{}}%
  \stackengine{2ex}{%
  \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[1.5ex]{#5}}\,%
  \stackengine{0.6ex}{%
  \stackengine{1.9ex}{#1}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
  }{#4}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
  \RHS$^{#6}$\RRHS%
  }{$#7$}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\savestack\Bond{\rule{1.2ex}{.5pt}}
\savestack{\PBond}{\rotatebox{90}{\Bond}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\stackunder{%
H\lewis{S}{..}{..}{..}{..}{}{}H\qquad
H\lewis{S}{\Bond}{\PBond}{\Bond}{\PBond}{}{}H%
}{\tiny\stackunder{Estructura de Lewis de la mol\'edula de sulfuro}{de hidr\'ogeno}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adapted/extended from my answer at [Draw Lewis structures like a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/draw-lewis-structures-like-a-book/137248#137248)

Comment: This doesn't use `chemfig` so I don't think its an answer to the question – especially since the task is rather easy with `chemfig`.

Comment: @clemens I guess things were slow on a Friday afternoon.  No one jumped in with a `chemfig` solution, so I threw this one out, having to figure out the bond-bars (if I understand the notation right).  But I'm not holding my breath for votes.

Comment: @clemensThe cited duplicate shows how to do the electron dots surrounding the atom, but does not show how to do the bars (bonds? or is it empty shells?).  That was one of the reasons I added an answer.

Comment: Yes, but it's not that hard to look in the manual and to search for `\lewis` once its clear that the command is there: `\setatomsep{1.7em}
H\Lewis{0:2:4:6:,S}H \quad \chemfig{H-\lewis{26,S}-H}`

Comment: Thank you very much @clemens. What you posted is just what I need right now. But it doesn't work if i want to do something like this but using O instead of H and put the electron pairs there. Or at least I think it doesn't work.

The idea is to use chemfig to represent bonds and electron pairs as :