# Writing Chemical Reactions - Lewis Structure

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How are you?

I'm having a hard time doing this chemical reaction with a Lewis structure, could someone help me?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you search the site for the keyword "Lewis", you will find many such questions that discuss this issue.  Here is one, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/draw-lewis-structures-like-a-book

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your compilable code ....

Comment: You can use also chemmacros-manual to pag. 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em, fixed length=true}
\setcharge{extra sep=3pt}
\schemestart
\chemfig{-\charge{90=\:}{N}=C=\charge{90=\:,270=\:}{O}}
\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{-\charge{90=\:}{N}=\charge{90=$ ^+ $}{C}-\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:,45=$ \;^- $}{O}}
\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{-\charge{90=\:,270=\:,135=$ ^-\; $}{N}-\charge{90=$ ^+ $}{C}=\charge{0=\:,90=\:}{O}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!!!!!! Thanks Thanks Thanks!!!!!